# Есть ли криптографическое API в HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html5, шифрование, криптография

Нужно решение для ассиметричного и симметричного шифрования на стороне клиента, предпочтительнее нативный жабаскриптовский. Или проверенная сторонняя библиотека, если нативного нет.

Https не нужен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В HTML криптографического API нет, так как этот язык обеспечивает представление страницы, а не работу с данными. Для JavaScript есть много библиотек, реализующих криптографические алгоритмы. Например, Crypto-JS от Google (симметричное шифрование) или pidCrypt (как симметричное, так и асимметричное).

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понимаю - [есть](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/), но оно еще окончательно не принято.  Не уверен насчет терминологии. Там используется JS, но, как я понимаю, когда оно будет окончательно принято - станет частью стандарта HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

У гугла, например, вот такое есть: [ссылка](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/)